# Ubuntu 16.04: Steam - "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast"

Tags: 16.04, steam

Having installed `nvidia-375`, Steam didn't work, so I reinstalled, to no effect. When I try to open Steam, I get the following error (with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose`):

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for 
appid(steam)/version(1493162727)
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-
gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/benedict/.drirc: No such 
file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/benedict/.drirc: No such 
file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Other answers have suggested I remove `libstdc++.so.6`, which I have done, so now my `~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` contains these:

```
libfreetype.so.6      libxcb.so.1        libXinerama.so.1.0.0
libfreetype.so.6.8.0  libxcb.so.1.1.0    libXrandr.so.2
libstdc++.so.6.0.21   libXdmcp.so.6      libXrandr.so.2.2.0
libX11.so.6           libXdmcp.so.6.0.0  libXrender.so.1
libX11.so.6.3.0       libXext.so.6       libXrender.so.1.3.0
libXau.so.6           libXext.so.6.4.0
libXau.so.6.0.0       libXinerama.so.1
```

I have an Nvidia Geforce 820M.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try, run it with docker container, based on my dockerfile
https://github.com/allenyllee/server_setup/blob/master/nvidia_docker/Dockerfile_cuda80

This dockerfile is based on official cuda image, modified to run all cuda samples with OpenGL, you should use nvidia-docker to build & run it.

This solves my similar problem while running windows program via WINE.